# H2 ORA-02420: missing schema authorization clause

Tags: oracle, jenkins, testing, h2, database-schema

I used authrization clause

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS XXX AUTHORIZATION sa;
```

but **h2** still throw exception:

> ```
> nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 
> ORA-02420: missing schema authorization clause
> ```

Here is the *jdbc url* :

```
jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;
```

and the version

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.214</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

It's working in my local environment, but didn't work in the jenkins during the test phase.

Comment: ORA-02420 is an error generated by Oracle. H2 uses different error codes.

Comment: `IF NOT EXISTS` cannot be used there as apparently considering you run the code at the Oracle's side.

Comment: I'm not sure `create schema` does what you think [in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-SCHEMA.html); are you trying to create a user really?